# Excel formula to search for one of multiple strings and return the string

Tags: arrays, excel

I have names that are listed with salutations (ex. Mr. Mrs. Dr.).  I am struggling with a formula that will search for the existence of those text strings, and, if one exists, return the salutation.

So, I would like the formula to look at "Dr. Nancy Briggs," and return "Dr."

Versions I have been trying include:
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Mr.","Mrs.","Dr."},C13)),LEFT(C13,FIND(" ",C13,1)-1),"")

=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Mr.",C24)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Mrs.",C24)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Dr.",C24))),LEFT(C24,FIND(" ",C24,1)-1),"")

- the salutations are always at the front, so I can extract them using the LEFT function.  But, ideally, I would like to extract them from anywhere.

The second formula works, but is clunky. Your help is so very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested IF:

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Mr.")),"Mr.",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Mrs.")),"Mrs.",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Dr.")),"Dr.","No Salutation")))
```

If you have OFFICE 365:

You can use CONCAT as an Array formula:

```
=CONCAT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Mr.","Mrs.","Dr."},C13)),{"Mr.","Mrs.","Dr."},"")
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter

Or IFS()

```
=IFS(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Mr.")),"Mr.",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Mrs.")),"Mrs.",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Dr.")),"Dr.",TRUE,"No Salutation")
```

The only real changes is that I am not trying to pull the return from the string as you only want the actual salutation.

Comment: Thank you so much!  The second one is exactly what I'm looking for!